# why my main image is not in the center in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

Looks fine in firefox but the image is not displaying in center.

In Chrome image is not aligned in the center of browser window

If you refresh the browser it get aligned to center & then get back to left after few second.

thank you for any help.
here is the [Demo Template.](http://www.centerwow.com/kids/WebPage_with_Banner/)
Thx.

css code:

```
html,body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      /*background: #FFF url("images/border.jpg") repeat-y center;*/
}
 #wrapper{
    margin:0 30px;
    width: 95%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

#anti-shadow-div{
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img { border: none; }
a { text-decoration: none; color: #2965a6; font-weight: bold;}
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #fca00e; }

/*---------- Divs ----------*/

/*#header {
      background: url("images/logo006.jpg") no-repeat center;
      height: 120px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
}*/





#header001 {
      background: url("images/logo001.jpg") no-repeat center top;width:890px;height:133px;
      height: 133px;
      width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 50px;
}


#indexheader{
background:#FFFFFF;
 height: 30px;
      width: 890px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 50px;
      }
#indeximg{
float:left;
}

#navibtn{
width:900px;
height:90px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.navibtn001{

background:url(images/automart.jpg) no-repeat;
width:200px;
height:90px;
}

.navibtn002{
background:url(images/cab.jpg) no-repeat;
width:900px;
height:90px;
}


#logo002{
      padding-top: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 890px;
      voice-family: "\"}\""; 
      voice-family:inherit;
      width: 850px;
}

/************
html>body #logo { width: 850px }  /* for opera */
/*
#logo a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
}  */
/*
#logo a {
      float: left;
      background: url("images/logo.jpg") no-repeat 0px 0px;
      width: 317px;
      height: 85px;
}

*******************/



/*---------- Divs ----------*/
#flsh{
background:url(images/vans/56%20dolpin/flv002.swf) no-repeat  left top;width:640px;height:480px;
height: 500px;
width: 650px;
margin: 0 auto;

}



/*******************/


#menubutton{
width:100%;
height:20px;
text-align:center;
}


#container {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: left;
      font: 90% Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0px auto;
      border-top: 3px solid #6fb2e6;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #ffb93f;
      background: #e5e5e5;
}  
* html #container {
      overflow: visible;
}

#content{
      float: right;
      width: 690px;
      background: #fff url(images/nav-edge.jpg) repeat-y;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      min-height: 380px;
}
* html #content {height: 380px; overflow: visible;}

#maincontent {
      float: left;
      float: right;
      padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 450px;
      voice-family: "\"}\""; 
      voice-family:inherit;
      width: 410px; 
}

#maincontent001 {
      float: left;
     /* float: right;*/
      padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 450px;
      voice-family: "\"}\""; 
      voice-family:inherit;
      width: 650px; 
}


#rightdiv{
      padding-top: 30px;
      float: right;
      width: 230px;
}

#rightdiv img{
      padding: 1px;
      border: 1px solid #6fb2e6;
}

#news{
      width: 210px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

/*---------- Navigation Menu ----------*/
#navcontainer {
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      min-height: 380px;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 180px;
}
* html #navcontainer {height: 380px; overflow: visible;}

.nav {
    width: 170px;
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 105%;
    left: 228px;
    top: 13px;
}

.nav li {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 3px 1px;
      padding: 0;

}

.nav li a {
      border: 1px solid #52a3e2;
      display: block;
      padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
      background: #6fb2e6;
      color: #e5ffff;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 170px;
      voice-family: "\"}\""; 
      voice-family:inherit;
      width: 160px; 
}

.nav li a:hover {
      background: #ffb93f;
      color: #949494;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
}

/*---------- Footer ----------*/
#footer {
      height: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
      font-size: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #6a6666;
      width: 890px;
      background: #fff;
}

#footerimg{
background:url("images/footer.jpg") no-repeat left top;width:890px;height:133px;
      height: 133px;
      width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }

#footeradd{
background:url(images/carsalelogo.jpg)no-repeat left top;width:890px;height:133px;
 height: 133px;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}



#footertextleft{
      margin-left: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 450px;
      float: left;
}

#footertextright{
      margin-right: 10px;
      text-align: right;
      width: 350px;
      float: right;
}

/*---------- Headings ----------*/
h1 { 
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;  
      font: 120% Arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #5c94bf;
}

.mainheading{
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 123%;      
}

h2 {
      padding-top: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      font: 110% arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #5c94bf;
}

#subtext{
      padding-top: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      font: 110% arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #5c94bf;
}




/*---------- Classes ----------*/
.underline{
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      width: 180px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ffb93f;
}

.subheading{
      font-weight: bold;
}

.submitbox{
      width: 215px;
      background: #b8d1e4;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.submitbox p{
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.submitbox button{
      font-size: 95%;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      color: #949494;
      border: none;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      font-weight: bold;
}

#maincontent ul{
      list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png)
}

.advert{
      width: 160px;
      padding: 5px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `margin: 0 auto;` to :

```
#anti-shadow-div {
   display: table;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```